# How to manually set order and labels of legend items in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am able to create my desired chart as a standard `ggplot2`

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(19205, 19236, 19266, 19205, 
19236, 19266, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19205, 
19236, 19266, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19205, 
19236, 19266, 19205, 19236, 19266), class = "Date"), Key = c("Average Hourly Earnings", 
"Average Hourly Earnings", "Average Hourly Earnings", "Case Shiller House Price Index", 
"Case Shiller House Price Index", "Case Shiller House Price Index", 
"HPA", "HPA", "HPA", "Industrial Production", "Industrial Production", 
"Industrial Production", "Personal Consumption Expenditures", 
"Personal Consumption Expenditures", "Personal Consumption Expenditures", 
"Retail Sales", "Retail Sales", "Retail Sales", "Capacity Utilisation", 
"Capacity Utilisation", "Capacity Utilisation", "Total Vehicle Sales", 
"Total Vehicle Sales", "Total Vehicle Sales", "Construction Spending", 
"Construction Spending", "Construction Spending"), Value = c(-0.223065575886151, 
-1.40315318073944, -1.91465670559936, -2.51599837113228, NA, 
NA, -2.39639074829503, NA, NA, -0.620070909725157, 0.438262897380392, 
-1.02195804568898, -1.18062194826764, -1.04966383725284, NA, 
-0.434581634758551, -0.671474725212731, -0.689827602986322, 0.814973303786158, 
0.792591156917412, 0.36832537554409, 2.29199981656987, 2.23432584415557, 
1.83201171904481, 0.283236872921727, 0.721164674024409, NA), 
    Color = c("#e6cc00", "#ff0000", "#ff0000", "#7b0000", NA, 
    NA, "#7b0000", NA, NA, "#e6cc00", "#ece75f", "#ff0000", "#ff0000", 
    "#ff0000", NA, "#e6cc00", "#e6cc00", "#e6cc00", "#ece75f", 
    "#ece75f", "#ece75f", "#0a5d00", "#0a5d00", "#0eff00", "#ece75f", 
    "#ece75f", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

p <- data2 %>% 
  {ggplot(.,aes(Date, Key, fill = Color)) +
      geom_tile() +
      theme_light() +
      scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend', breaks = c('NA','#0a5d00','#0eff00', "#ece75f",'#e6cc00','#ff0000','#7b0000'),
                          labels = c("NA",'> 2 Standard Deviations from mean', 'Between 1 and 2 Standard Deviations from mean',
                                     'Between 0 and 1 Standard Deviations from mean', 'Between 0 and -1 Standard Deviations from mean',
                                     'Between -1 and -2 Standard Deviations from mean', '> -2 Standard Deviations from mean')) 
  } 

p
```

[image]

However when I try to convert it into an interactive chart using `ggplotly`, it ignores all of the customisations to the legend that I did in the `ggplot`. Is there a way to manually set the order of the legend items as well as the labels in the legend as I have done in my `ggplot`?

```
p %>% ggplotly(tooltip = c('Date','Key')) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this happen, I created another variable in your data frame. I copied the breaks and labels from your original call to `scale_fill_manual`.

I want to point out that in the viewer pane, the legend will reflect as a stack if the window isn't large enough for it to reflect the labels horizontally.

The new variable.

```
data2 <- data2 %>%
    mutate(labs = Color %>% as.factor() %>% plyr::mapvalues(
        # copied from breaks; NA removed
        from = c('#0a5d00','#0eff00',"#ece75f",'#e6cc00','#ff0000','#7b0000'),
        # copied from labels; NA removed
        to = c('> 2 Standard Deviations from mean', 
               'Between 1 and 2 Standard Deviations from mean',
               'Between 0 and 1 Standard Deviations from mean', 
               'Between 0 and -1 Standard Deviations from mean',
               'Between -1 and -2 Standard Deviations from mean',
               '> -2 Standard Deviations from mean')))
```

A modification to the plot—setting, filter out the NA, change `fill` to `fill = labs`, and instead of `scale_fill_identity`, I've used `scale_fill_manual`. In that call, you will map the colors to the color labels. (Instead of the reverse, which is what you did originally.)

```
(p <- data2 %>% filter(!is.na(Color)) %>% 
    ggplot(.,aes(Date, Key, fill = labs)) +
    geom_tile() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = levels(as.factor(data2$Color)),
                      breaks = levels(as.factor(data2$labs))))
```

I've got 2 different versions for you to look at for this as a Plotly object. The first centers the legend on the plot (just the gridded area). The second is left-aligned.

```
p %>% ggplotly() %>% 
  layout(legend = list(xanchor = "center", y = -.2,
                       x = .5, orientation = "h"))

p %>% ggplotly() %>% 
  layout(legend = list(xanchor = "left", y = -.2,
                       x = -.2, orientation = "h"))
```

The first image is the centered variation; the second is the left-aligned version.

[image]

[image]

FYI: If you were partial to the order in which the labels were provided in `ggplot` (y-axis), you can force Plotly to respect them if you make them an ordered factor.

Your original legend title was `Color`. If you want that to be the legend title for this plot, simply add it to the `layout` call.

```
p %>% ggplotly() %>% 
  layout(legend = list(xanchor = "left", y = -.2,
                       x = -.2, orientation = "h",
                       title = list(text = "Color")))
```

[image]

Comment: this is a perfect solution! Thanks so much

Comment: I'm having some trouble with reordering my legend entries, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Make `Color` an ordered factor before creating `labs`.  You can do this in the same `mutate` call. `mutate(Color = factor(Color, c(copy and paste from breaks), ordered = T), labs = Color %>% plyr::mapvalues...` (note that I took `as.factor` out of the creation of `labs` since Color is already a factor).